# the use of Renderer2 in angular4 - cannot add it to import array

Tags: angular

If I use `import { Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';` in my shared.module in angular 4,
why can't I also add it in the import array such as:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        Renderer2,
  ...
 ]
```

Adding it in the import gives an error. Here is why I need Renderer2:

myComponent.html (part of my shared.module):

```
<input #searchElem type="text">
```

myComponent.ts

```
 constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {
    }

const element = this.renderer.selectRootElement('#searchElem');
setTimeout(() => element.focus(), 0);
```

This is done to be able to set the focus of an element.

Comment: Renderer2 is supported by angular5. please use Renderer for the angular 4

Comment: According to the [docs](https://v4.angular.io/api/core/Renderer2), Renderer2 already existed in v4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Renderer2` is an injectable (service) part of Angular core. It's not a module. The [import property in `@NgModule` is to import other modules](https://angular.io/api/core/NgModule#imports). You should be able to use `Renderer2` in your component the way you have it, but simply remove it from the module imports.

Comment: Ok Sam, thank you. Any thoughts on why I get The selector "#searchElem" did not match any elements? I do have #searchElem in the html

Comment: Ah, if you need to get a reference to an element in the template of a component, you don't need `Renderer2`. Use [ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) instead.

Comment: Ex: 
`@ViewChild('searchElem') searchElem: ElementRef`

Comment: Yes, actually that's what I am using. I have `@ViewChild('searchElem') : ElementRef` and then if I do`this.searchElem.nativeElement as HTMLInputElement).focus();` ,  nativeElement can be problematic and cause errors, hence why I was trying my luck with Renderer

Comment: Oh are you attempting to access the `searchElement` property in the constructor? Since Angular has to query the element first, the earliest you can access it is in the `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook. [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x1ddkx?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) is a simple example.

Answer (score 0):

```
imports
```

imports describe which dependencies this module has.
If your module depends on other modules, you list them here. example

```
 imports: [
    BrowserModule, HttpClientModule,DataTableModule, AppRoutingModule,
  ],
```

The short answer is that you put something in your NgModule’s imports if you’re going
to be using it in your *templates* or with *dependency injection*.

`import` statement is used to import other typescript files and class

```
import {className} from 'filePath';
```